# Artifactory OSS: metadata service logs Project update error

Tags: artifactory

I updated Artifactory OSS from 7.15.4 to 7.24.3. Everythings seems running but in the console.log I get all 5 Minutes an entry like this one:

> 2021-08-21T07:33:19.081Z [34;1m[jfmd ][0m [31;1m[ERROR][0m [672d2eb628a9855d] [compatibility_logger.go:28    ] [main                ] - Project update error: rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded [access_client]

In the medata-service.log I get these errors after or during restart:

> 2021-08-25T15:02:37.582Z [jfmd ] [ERROR] [40fc5c5d4d36c69 ] [compatibility_logger.go:28    ] [main                ] - Refreshing permissions cache invalidation gRPC stream - got an error (status code: 13) - resubscribe expected [access_client]
> 2021-08-25T15:02:37.582Z [jfmd ] [ERROR] [40fc5c5d4d36c69 ] [compatibility_logger.go:28    ] [main                ] - Project update error: rpc error: code = Internal desc = server closed the stream without sending trailers [access_client]
> 2021-08-25T15:02:37.582Z [jfmd ] [ERROR] [40fc5c5d4d36c69 ] [compatibility_logger.go:28    ] [main                ] - Refreshing project change events gRPC stream - got an error (status code: 13) - resubscribe expected [access_client]
> 2021-08-25T15:02:37.591Z [jfmd ] [ERROR] [40fc5c5d4d36c69 ] [compatibility_logger.go:28    ] [main                ] - Project update error: rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = Not Found: HTTP status code 404; transport: received the unexpected content-type "text/plain; charset=utf-8" [access_client]
> 2021-08-25T15:02:37.591Z [jfmd ] [ERROR] [40fc5c5d4d36c69 ] [compatibility_logger.go:28    ] [main                ] - Refreshing project change events gRPC stream - got an error (status code: 12) - resubscribe expected [access_client]

I can't find anything about it. What it means and how i could resolve it. Has anybody an idea what the problem could be?

Thanks
Michael

#UPDATE

Console.log before the error starts:

```
    2021-08-21T07:28:20.529Z [36m[jfrou][0m [34m[INFO ][0m [                ] [server_configuration.go:61    ] [main                ] - Server configuration reloaded on localhost:8046
2021-08-21T07:28:20.529Z [36m[jfrou][0m [34m[INFO ][0m [                ] [server_configuration.go:61    ] [main                ] - Server configuration reloaded on localhost:8049
2021-08-21T07:28:20.530Z [36m[jfrou][0m [34m[INFO ][0m [                ] [server_configuration.go:61    ] [main                ] - Server configuration reloaded on :8082
2021-08-21T07:28:20.626Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [70e937c2d18bcda8] [o.a.s.a.AccessServiceImpl:456 ] [art-init            ] - Initialized access service successfully with client id 7779704, closing old client id [null]
2021-08-21T07:28:20.626Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [70e937c2d18bcda8] [o.a.s.a.AccessServiceImpl:1360] [art-init            ] - Updating access configuration with password expiration data
2021-08-21T07:28:20.790Z [33m[jffe ][39m [31m[1m[ERROR][22m[39m [                ] [                              ] [main                ] - ArtifactoryClient::http [get] request to /api/system/ping failed with 503 code
2021-08-21T07:28:21.017Z [36m[jfrou][0m [31m[WARN ][0m [1389b52b3df1ce7e] [local_topology.go:256         ] [main                ] - Readiness test failed with the following error: "required node services are missing or unhealthy"
2021-08-21T07:28:21.175Z [34;1m[jfmd ][0m [31m[WARN ][0m [672d2eb628a9855d] [versions_package_id_ordinal_in] [main                ] - Running DB indexes [md_version_pkgid_ordinal_idx,md_versions_package_id_idx,md_versions_ordinal_idx] maintenance in the background, it might cause some slowness in the Metadata service [BatchEndKey][1] [BatchKey][versionsPackageIdOrdinalIndexTask] [BatchStartKey][0] [versions_package_id_ordinal_index_task] [workerNumber][1]
2021-08-21T07:28:21.235Z [34;1m[jfmd ][0m [31m[WARN ][0m [672d2eb628a9855d] [versions_package_id_ordinal_in] [main                ] - Finished with DB indexes [[md_version_pkgid_ordinal_idx md_versions_package_id_idx md_versions_ordinal_idx]] background maintenance, Metadata service is back to normal [BatchEndKey][1] [BatchKey][versionsPackageIdOrdinalIndexTask] [BatchStartKey][0] [versions_package_id_ordinal_index_task] [workerNumber][1]
2021-08-21T07:28:21.812Z [33m[jffe ][39m [31m[1m[ERROR][22m[39m [                ] [                              ] [main                ] - ArtifactoryClient::http [get] request to /api/system/ping failed with 503 code
2021-08-21T07:28:22.255Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [70e937c2d18bcda8] [tegrationCleanupServiceImpl:75] [art-init            ] - Using generated cron 0 12 3 ? * * for jobs table cleanup
2021-08-21T07:28:22.548Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [70e937c2d18bcda8] [d.c.m.ConverterManagerImpl:212] [art-init            ] - Triggering POST_INIT conversion, from 7.15.4 to 7.24.3
2021-08-21T07:28:22.550Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [70e937c2d18bcda8] [d.c.m.ConverterManagerImpl:215] [art-init            ] - Finished POST_INIT conversion, current version is: 7.24.3
2021-08-21T07:28:22.551Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [70e937c2d18bcda8] [d.c.m.ConverterManagerImpl:249] [art-init            ] - Updating database properties to running version CompoundVersionDetails{version=7.24.3, buildNumber='LOCAL', timestamp=1167040800000}
2021-08-21T07:28:22.608Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [70e937c2d18bcda8] [ifactoryApplicationContext:560] [art-init            ] - Artifactory application context set to READY by refresh
2021-08-21T07:28:22.641Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [c70b31da2cdf896b] [adsFolderCleanupServiceImpl:52] [art-exec-4          ] - Starting docker temp folder cleanup
2021-08-21T07:28:22.643Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [c70b31da2cdf896b] [adsFolderCleanupServiceImpl:54] [art-exec-4          ] - Docker temp folder cleanup finished, time took: 2 millis
2021-08-21T07:28:22.654Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [70e937c2d18bcda8] [.w.NodeEventTaskManagerImpl:41] [art-init            ] - Event management started on behalf of Event Operator with ID 'metadata-operator-events'
2021-08-21T07:28:22.678Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [70e937c2d18bcda8] [o.a.s.s.StorageServiceImpl:529] [art-init            ] - Scheduling CalculateReposStorageSummaryJob to run at '0 1 * ? * *'
2021-08-21T07:28:22.688Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [70e937c2d18bcda8] [o.a.s.s.StorageServiceImpl:558] [art-init            ] - LogStorageStatusJob disabled and not scheduled to run
2021-08-21T07:28:22.740Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [70e937c2d18bcda8] [o.a.m.f.MetricsServiceImpl:135] [art-init            ] - Metric Framework Service is enabled: false
2021-08-21T07:28:22.815Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [70e937c2d18bcda8] [o.a.s.a.AccessServiceImpl:1681] [art-init            ] - Successful register of Artifactory serviceId jf-artifactory@c0349e2a-f2d7-44ab-8a02-3459c2eabbb4 in Access Federation
2021-08-21T07:28:22.825Z [33m[jffe ][39m [31m[1m[ERROR][22m[39m [                ] [                              ] [main                ] - ArtifactoryClient::http [get] request to /api/system/ping failed with 503 code
2021-08-21T07:28:22.924Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [70e937c2d18bcda8] [ctoryContextConfigListener:271] [art-init            ] - Artifactory (jfrt) service initialization completed in 29.280 seconds. Listening on port: 8081
2021-08-21T07:28:22.934Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [d.DatabaseConverterRunnable:37] [pool-84-thread-1    ] - Starting Async converter thread.
2021-08-21T07:28:22.935Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [ncDBSqlConditionalConverter:33] [pool-84-thread-1    ] - Starting attempt #1 of async conversion for v225_change_nodes_node_name_idx
2021-08-21T07:28:22.936Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [ncDBSqlConditionalConverter:35] [pool-84-thread-1    ] - Conversion of v225_change_nodes_node_name_idx finished successfully.
2021-08-21T07:28:22.939Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [ncDBSqlConditionalConverter:33] [pool-84-thread-1    ] - Starting attempt #1 of async conversion for v225_change_nodes_node_path_idx
2021-08-21T07:28:22.940Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [ncDBSqlConditionalConverter:35] [pool-84-thread-1    ] - Conversion of v225_change_nodes_node_path_idx finished successfully.
2021-08-21T07:28:22.941Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [ncDBSqlConditionalConverter:33] [pool-84-thread-1    ] - Starting attempt #1 of async conversion for v225_change_nodes_node_repo_path_idx
2021-08-21T07:28:22.941Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [ncDBSqlConditionalConverter:35] [pool-84-thread-1    ] - Conversion of v225_change_nodes_node_repo_path_idx finished successfully.
2021-08-21T07:28:22.943Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [ncDBSqlConditionalConverter:33] [pool-84-thread-1    ] - Starting attempt #1 of async conversion for v225_add_bundle_files_node_id_index
2021-08-21T07:28:23.025Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [ncDBSqlConditionalConverter:35] [pool-84-thread-1    ] - Conversion of v225_add_bundle_files_node_id_index finished successfully.
2021-08-21T07:28:23.035Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [ncDBSqlConditionalConverter:33] [pool-84-thread-1    ] - Starting attempt #1 of async conversion for v229_node_events_tmp_event_id_idx
2021-08-21T07:28:23.047Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [s.d.v.c.DbSqlConverterUtil:101] [pool-84-thread-1    ] - Starting schema conversion: /conversion/derby/derby_v229_node_events_tmp_event_id_idx.sql
2021-08-21T07:28:23.073Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [s.d.v.c.DbSqlConverterUtil:103] [pool-84-thread-1    ] - Finished schema conversion: /conversion/derby/derby_v229_node_events_tmp_event_id_idx.sql
2021-08-21T07:28:23.074Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [ncDBSqlConditionalConverter:35] [pool-84-thread-1    ] - Conversion of v229_node_events_tmp_event_id_idx finished successfully.
2021-08-21T07:28:23.252Z [34;1m[jfmd ][0m [31m[WARN ][0m [672d2eb628a9855d] [ver_repos_lead_file_path_index] [main                ] - Running DB index [md_ver_repos_lead_file_pth_idx] maintenance in the background, it might cause some slowness in the Metadata service [BatchEndKey][1] [BatchKey][verReposLeadFilePathIndexIndexTask] [BatchStartKey][0] [ver_repos_lead_file_path_index_task] [workerNumber][1]
2021-08-21T07:28:23.496Z [34;1m[jfmd ][0m [31m[WARN ][0m [672d2eb628a9855d] [ver_repos_lead_file_path_index] [main                ] - Finished with DB index [md_ver_repos_lead_file_pth_idx] background maintenance, Metadata service is back to normal [BatchEndKey][1] [BatchKey][verReposLeadFilePathIndexIndexTask] [BatchStartKey][0] [ver_repos_lead_file_path_index_task] [workerNumber][1]
2021-08-21T07:28:23.833Z [33m[jffe ][39m [31m[1m[ERROR][22m[39m [                ] [                              ] [main                ] - ArtifactoryClient::http [get] request to /api/system/ping failed with 503 code
2021-08-21T07:28:24.840Z [33m[jffe ][39m [31m[1m[ERROR][22m[39m [                ] [                              ] [main                ] - ArtifactoryClient::http [get] request to /api/system/ping failed with 503 code
2021-08-21T07:28:25.957Z [33m[jffe ][39m [31m[1m[ERROR][22m[39m [                ] [                              ] [main                ] - ArtifactoryClient::http [get] request to /api/system/ping failed with 503 code
2021-08-21T07:28:26.017Z [36m[jfrou][0m [31m[WARN ][0m [311a50c5e0280291] [local_topology.go:256         ] [main                ] - Readiness test failed with the following error: "required node services are missing or unhealthy"
2021-08-21T07:28:26.958Z [33m[jffe ][39m [34m[INFO ][39m [                ] [                              ] [main                ] - pinging artifactory, attempt number 50
2021-08-21T07:28:26.965Z [33m[jffe ][39m [31m[1m[ERROR][22m[39m [                ] [                              ] [main                ] - ArtifactoryClient::http [get] request to /api/system/ping failed with 503 code
2021-08-21T07:28:26.965Z [33m[jffe ][39m [34m[INFO ][39m [                ] [                              ] [main                ] - pinging artifactory attempt number 50 failed with code : undefined
2021-08-21T07:28:28.021Z [33m[jffe ][39m [31m[1m[ERROR][22m[39m [                ] [                              ] [main                ] - ArtifactoryClient::http [get] request to /api/system/ping failed with 503 code
2021-08-21T07:28:29.101Z [33m[jffe ][39m [31m[1m[ERROR][22m[39m [                ] [                              ] [main                ] - ArtifactoryClient::http [get] request to /api/system/ping failed with 503 code
2021-08-21T07:28:30.109Z [33m[jffe ][39m [31m[1m[ERROR][22m[39m [                ] [                              ] [main                ] - ArtifactoryClient::http [get] request to /api/system/ping failed with 503 code
2021-08-21T07:28:31.583Z [36m[jfrou][0m [31m[WARN ][0m [7f23355140d7ce99] [local_topology.go:256         ] [main                ] - Readiness test failed with the following error: "required node services are missing or unhealthy"
2021-08-21T07:28:31.602Z [33m[jffe ][39m [34m[INFO ][39m [                ] [                              ] [main                ] - artifactory was pinged successfully
2021-08-21T07:28:31.604Z [33m[jffe ][39m [34m[INFO ][39m [                ] [                              ] [main                ] - setting service id - jffe@000
2021-08-21T07:28:31.834Z [1;33m[jfac ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [5fc9900945b9b96e] [s.r.NodeRegistryServiceImpl:68] [27.0.0.1-8040-exec-8] - Cluster join: Successfully joined jffe@000 with node id nodeX
2021-08-21T07:28:31.853Z [33m[jffe ][39m [34m[INFO ][39m [                ] [                              ] [main                ] - Cluster join: Successfully joined the cluster
2021-08-21T07:28:31.975Z [36m[jfrou][0m [34m[INFO ][0m [                ] [server_configuration.go:465   ] [main                ] - Skipping same configuration for provider file
2021-08-21T07:28:31.993Z [33m[jffe ][39m [34m[INFO ][39m [                ] [                              ] [main                ] - UI service successfully registered on router, serviceId: jffe@000
2021-08-21T07:28:32.625Z [33m[jffe ][39m [34m[INFO ][39m [                ] [                              ] [main                ] - Recurring tasks started
Sat, 21 Aug 2021 07:28:33 GMT helmet deprecated helmet.featurePolicy is deprecated (along with the HTTP header) and will be removed in helmet@4. You can use the `feature-policy` module instead. at ../app/frontend/bin/server/dist/bundle.js:13834:24
2021-08-21T07:28:33.174Z [33m[jffe ][39m [34m[INFO ][39m [                ] [                              ] [main                ] - frontend (jffe) service initialization completed in 56.22 seconds. Listening on port: port 8070
2021-08-21T07:28:36.072Z [36m[jfrou][0m [34m[INFO ][0m [5e15997735a74857] [local_topology.go:270         ] [main                ] - 
###############################################################
###   All services started successfully in 61.943 seconds   ###
###############################################################
2021-08-21T07:28:36.098Z [36m[jfrou][0m [34m[INFO ][0m [                ] [server_configuration.go:61    ] [main                ] - Server configuration reloaded on localhost:8049
2021-08-21T07:28:36.098Z [36m[jfrou][0m [34m[INFO ][0m [                ] [server_configuration.go:61    ] [main                ] - Server configuration reloaded on :8082
2021-08-21T07:28:36.099Z [36m[jfrou][0m [34m[INFO ][0m [                ] [server_configuration.go:61    ] [main                ] - Server configuration reloaded on localhost:8046
2021-08-21T07:28:36.140Z [1;33m[jfac ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [CertificateFileHandlerBase:181] [c-default-executor-1] - Loading root certificate from database.
2021-08-21T07:28:36.217Z [1;33m[jfac ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [2530a31ed464ef0c] [.s.b.AccessProjectBootstrap:89] [pool-66-thread-2    ] - Finished initializing Projects permissions in 81.5 millis
2021-08-21T07:28:36.299Z [1;33m[jfac ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [CertificateFileHandlerBase:328] [c-default-executor-1] - [ACCESS BOOTSTRAP] Saved new root certificate at: /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/access/keys/root.crt
2021-08-21T07:28:36.301Z [1;33m[jfac ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [CertificateFileHandlerBase:190] [c-default-executor-1] - Finished loading root certificate from database.
2021-08-21T07:28:36.301Z [1;33m[jfac ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [CertificateFileHandlerBase:181] [c-default-executor-1] - Loading ca certificate from database.
2021-08-21T07:28:36.422Z [1;33m[jfac ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [CertificateFileHandlerBase:328] [c-default-executor-1] - [ACCESS BOOTSTRAP] Saved new ca certificate at: /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/access/keys/ca.crt
2021-08-21T07:28:36.423Z [1;33m[jfac ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [CertificateFileHandlerBase:190] [c-default-executor-1] - Finished loading ca certificate from database.
2021-08-21T07:28:36.431Z [1;33m[jfac ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [alConfigurationServiceBase:182] [c-default-executor-1] - Loading configuration from db finished successfully
2021-08-21T07:28:38.112Z [36m[jfrou][0m [34m[INFO ][0m [                ] [server_configuration.go:61    ] [main                ] - Server configuration reloaded on localhost:8046
2021-08-21T07:28:38.112Z [36m[jfrou][0m [34m[INFO ][0m [                ] [server_configuration.go:61    ] [main                ] - Server configuration reloaded on localhost:8049
2021-08-21T07:28:38.112Z [36m[jfrou][0m [34m[INFO ][0m [                ] [server_configuration.go:61    ] [main                ] - Server configuration reloaded on :8082
2021-08-21T07:28:39.537Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [                ] [o.j.c.ConfigWrapperImpl:342   ] [pool-44-thread-1    ] - [Node ID: nodeX]  detected local  modify for config 'artifactory/config/security/access/access.admin.token'
2021-08-21T07:28:43.664Z [33m[jffe ][39m [31m[WARN ][39m [66cd9108b9cd26f9] [                              ] [main                ] - topology is missing, can't decide if service exists, will return false
2021-08-21T07:28:43.673Z [33m[jffe ][39m [31m[WARN ][39m [66cd9108b9cd26f9] [                              ] [main                ] - topology is missing, can't decide if service exists, will return false
2021-08-21T07:28:44.392Z [33m[jffe ][39m [31m[WARN ][39m [1062901fde61dfc6] [                              ] [main                ] - topology is missing, can't decide if service exists, will return false
2021-08-21T07:28:44.392Z [33m[jffe ][39m [31m[WARN ][39m [1062901fde61dfc6] [                              ] [main                ] - topology is missing, can't decide if service exists, will return false
2021-08-21T07:28:44.392Z [33m[jffe ][39m [31m[WARN ][39m [1062901fde61dfc6] [                              ] [main                ] - topology is missing, can't decide if service exists, will return false
2021-08-21T07:28:45.482Z [33m[jffe ][39m [31m[WARN ][39m [4e1961812d24332a] [                              ] [main                ] - topology is missing, can't decide if service exists, will return false
2021-08-21T07:28:45.483Z [33m[jffe ][39m [31m[WARN ][39m [4e1961812d24332a] [                              ] [main                ] - topology is missing, can't decide if service exists, will return false
2021-08-21T07:28:45.683Z [33m[jffe ][39m [31m[WARN ][39m [a648f90bf2d7102 ] [                              ] [main                ] - topology is missing, can't decide if service exists, will return false
2021-08-21T07:28:45.683Z [33m[jffe ][39m [31m[WARN ][39m [a648f90bf2d7102 ] [                              ] [main                ] - topology is missing, can't decide if service exists, will return false
2021-08-21T07:28:45.683Z [33m[jffe ][39m [31m[WARN ][39m [a648f90bf2d7102 ] [                              ] [main                ] - topology is missing, can't decide if service exists, will return false
2021-08-21T07:28:46.535Z [33m[jffe ][39m [31m[WARN ][39m [503666ed4b13889 ] [                              ] [main                ] - topology is missing, can't decide if service exists, will return false
2021-08-21T07:28:46.536Z [33m[jffe ][39m [31m[WARN ][39m [503666ed4b13889 ] [                              ] [main                ] - topology is missing, can't decide if service exists, will return false
2021-08-21T07:28:46.536Z [33m[jffe ][39m [31m[WARN ][39m [503666ed4b13889 ] [                              ] [main                ] - topology is missing, can't decide if service exists, will return false
2021-08-21T07:28:52.919Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [6b8dfc5cbb3ed2a4] [a.e.EventsLogCleanUpService:69] [art-exec-3          ] - Starting cleanup of old events from event log
2021-08-21T07:28:53.016Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [6b8dfc5cbb3ed2a4] [.e.EventsLogCleanUpService:105] [art-exec-3          ] - Cleanup of old events from event log finished
2021-08-21T07:30:52.536Z [33m[jffe ][39m [31m[1m[ERROR][22m[39m [139a17c81a46c969] [                              ] [main                ] - ArtifactoryClient::http [get] request to /api/system/nodes failed with 403 code
2021-08-21T07:30:52.541Z [33m[jffe ][39m [31m[1m[ERROR][22m[39m [139a17c81a46c969] [                              ] [main                ] - Error: Request failed with status code 403
    at createError (/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/frontend/bin/server/dist/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/frontend/bin/server/dist/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/frontend/bin/server/dist/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:260:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
2021-08-21T07:31:12.829Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [31m[WARN ][0;39m [1b0e83537f9e0c72] [a.l.s.SumoLogicServiceImpl:227] [http-nio-8081-exec-4] - Unable to refresh Sumo Logic token, returning previously associated token
2021-08-21T07:33:02.254Z [shell] [38;5;69m[INFO ][0m [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:522       ] [main] - Resolved .replicator.enabled (true) from /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
2021-08-21T07:33:02.881Z [shell] [38;5;69m[INFO ][0m [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:522       ] [main] - Resolved .artifactory.port (8081) from /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
2021-08-21T07:33:02.996Z [shell] [38;5;69m[INFO ][0m [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:522       ] [main] - Resolved .artifactory.tomcat.connector.maxThreads (200) from /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
2021-08-21T07:33:03.118Z [shell] [38;5;69m[INFO ][0m [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:522       ] [main] - Resolved .access.tomcat.connector.maxThreads (50) from /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
2021-08-21T07:33:03.491Z [shell] [38;5;69m[INFO ][0m [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:522       ] [main] - Resolved .shared.extraJavaOpts (__sensitive_key_hidden___) from /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
2021-08-21T07:33:03.589Z [shell] [38;5;69m[INFO ][0m [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:522       ] [main] - Resolved .shared.extraJavaOpts (__sensitive_key_hidden___) from /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
2021-08-21T07:33:04.062Z [shell] [38;5;69m[INFO ][0m [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:522       ] [main] - Resolved .shared.database.type (derby) from /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
2021-08-21T07:33:04.314Z [shell] [38;5;69m[INFO ][0m [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:522       ] [main] - Resolved .shared.database.url (__sensitive_key_hidden___) from /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
2021-08-21T07:33:05.339Z [shell] [38;5;69m[INFO ][0m [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:522       ] [main] - Resolved .shared.extraJavaOpts (__sensitive_key_hidden___) from /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
2021-08-21T07:33:06.253Z [shell] [38;5;69m[INFO ][0m [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:522       ] [main] - Resolved .replicator.enabled (true) from /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
2021-08-21T07:33:19.081Z [34;1m[jfmd ][0m [31;1m[ERROR][0m [672d2eb628a9855d] [compatibility_logger.go:28    ] [main                ] - Project update error: rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded [access_client]
2021-08-21T07:38:19.082Z [34;1m[jfmd ][0m [31;1m[ERROR][0m [672d2eb628a9855d] [compatibility_logger.go:28    ] [main                ] - Project update error: rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded [access_client]
```

Comment: Are you sure Artifactory is working as expected? Could you check the access-service.log for any errors and compare it with the metadata-service.log's timestamp? In these logs shared, metadata fails to connect with the Access service

Comment: In the access-service.log I get just INFO Message. No correlation with the metada-service.log

Comment: @MichaelM can you share the output of console.log file? or if you're on docker the stdout of the container around the time of these logs

Comment: @maxyor6040, does the additional log helps or should i send you more informations?

Comment: @MichaelM can you share a longer snippet?
from this section I see jffe server is also unable to communicate with Access server

Comment: @maxyor6040, i added some more log content. All the log content is right after i did the update from 7.15.4 to 7.24.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error should be debug log and safe to ignore:

> Project update error: rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded [access_client]

(I created an internal ticket to hide this)

Error 12 usually means access server is down or at least not available to metadata. I was not able to reproduce the issue. You can check if access is available buy a simple curl command:

```
curl localhost:8082/access/api/v1/system/ping
```

You should get:

```
ok
```

If not you should check the reason. Usually going to localhost:8082 in the browser shows a UI error page with details.

FYI if you're not working with permissions and projects you shouldn't be impacted by this issue.(I suspect you're not if you use OSS)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The curl command returns OK and I don't work with projects. Do you have a link to the ticket, that i can follow it?

Comment: I can only create internal tickets that are not visible in the public JIRA. The ticket key is JA-2428

Comment: FYI fixed on 7.28.0. Will be released soon. Let me know if you still encounter any issues after the upgrade